# Grails Spring Security UI Requestmap Configuration

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

Im currently working on a Grails application and use the Spring Security framework with the Core and UI Plugins.

Nearly everything is working fine: User creation, editing, deleting, etc. The only problem is the requestmap, which is not working properly. When I call requestmap/create I get the following error:

```
URI /xxx/requestmap/create
Class java.lang.NullPointerException
Message Cannot get property 'clazz' on null object

Around line 81 of grails-app/controllers/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ui/AbstractS2UiController.groovy
78: }
79:
80: protected Class<?> lookupRequestmapClass() {
81:     grailsApplication.getDomainClass(lookupRequestmapClassName()).clazz
82: }
83:}
```

I configured Spring Security in my Config.groovy as follows:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'xxx.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'xxx.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'xxx.Role'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
```

I also use the following plugins in my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.1"
    compile ':cache:1.0.0'

    // Spring Security Core
    compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"

    // Spring Security UI (+ Dependencies)
    compile ":spring-security-ui:0.2"
    compile ":mail:1.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.7.2"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.15"
    compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"

    // Twitter Bootstrap
    // exlude is workaround for svn issue with bootstrap and grails 2.1.x
    compile (":twitter-bootstrap:2.0.2.25") { excludes 'svn' }
    runtime ':fields:1.3'
}
```

The requestmap search form appears, but throws an exception when searching:

```
URI /xxx/requestmap/requestmapSearch
Class org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException
Message xxx.Requestmap is not mapped [SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r) FROM xxx.Requestmap r WHERE 1=1 ]
Around line 46 of grails-app/controllers/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ui/RequestmapController.groovy
43:         }
44:     }
45:
46:     int totalCount = lookupUserClass().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r) $hql", queryParams)[0]
47:
48:     Integer max = params.int('max')
49:     Integer offset = params.int('offset')
```

I'm working on this error for a while now, did everything I found in the documentation. Is this a bug in Spring Security when combining with another plugin or what happens here? Without requestmaps the Spring Security UI plugin is senseless for me. I need that to work.

Answer (score 1):

In config.groovy:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType

grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
grails.plugins.springsecurity.requestMap.className = "sa.Requestmap"
```

In above `"sa.Requestmap"`, `sa` is a package name and `Requestmap` is a domain class as below:

```
package sa

class Requestmap {
  String url
  String configAttribute

  static mapping = {
    cache true
  }

  static constraints = {
    url blank : false, unique : true
    configAttribute blank : false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify a package (replaced with xxx) in `grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName` and 
`grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName` but not in `grails.plugins.springsecurity.requestMap.className`, it's just `'Requestmap'` - is that a typo?

The other error is different (a GORM issue but not a UI plugin configuration issue) - "xxx.Requestmap is not mapped". That indicates the domain class is wrong. Is it in grails-app/domain with the User and Role classes? Is it in the correct folder for its package? My guess is that it was in the default package but you moved it to the xxx package but didn't add a package statement.